# How much data do I need to properly train my ML model?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I collected 8800 samples total, but after data cleaning and outlier detection I was left with **3507** samples.

Is this enough to put through machine learning models? (lasso, linear regression, decision tree)
Should I scrape more?

I expect more data is needed, but I want to check with others before wasting time.

Also, how much data should I use for training and testing?

Comment: How many attributes does each sample have? (# of dependant variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to Machine Learning, ***more data is always better***

In general, as your model gets more complex, you'll need more data to prevent overfitting.

For example, a single-variable linear regression requires less data to train than a convolutional neural network. This is because *the neural network has more weights* than the single-variable model.

Unfortunately, ***a simple model has less predictive power than a complex one.*** In our example, this means the linear regression will yield a prediction farther from the actual value than a neural network when trying to model a variable that depends on more than the single input.

As for train/test split, I recommend randomly ordering all the data, and then using 80% for training and 20% for testing. Repeating this process multiple times to check if your model is a good fit regardless of training data selected is called [K-Fold Cross Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72319891/application-and-deployment-of-k-fold-cross-validation?rq=2)